# Despite using backslash dollar sign, error persists

Tags: math-mode, symbols, errors

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\begin{document}
\title{Kubuntu Setup}

Don't forget your architecture is not i386, but x86_64.  Better to use {\tt  \$(uname -i)} instead of manually specifying this

\end{document}
```

Gives:

> ! Missing $ inserted.  
>                   $ l.11 ...et your architecture is not i386, but x86_
>                                                     64.  Better to use
>   {\tt  ...
>
> ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem is the underscore. Use `x86\textunderscore 64` or `x86\_64`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\begin{document}
\title{Kubuntu Setup}

Don't forget your architecture is not i386, but x86\textunderscore 64.  Better to use \texttt{\$(uname -i)} instead of manually specifying this

\end{document}
```

I also change `tt` to `\texttt`. Alternative you can use `\ttfamily`. For more information about this topic read [l2tabu](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/info/l2tabu)

Quoted from l2tabu:

> **Why not use obsolete commands?** Obsolete commands do not support
>   LATeX2ε’s new font selection scheme, or NFSS. `{\bf foo}`, for
>   example, resets all font attributes which had been set earlier before
>   it prints foo in bold face. This is why you cannot simply define a
>   bold-italics style by `{\it \bf Test}` only. (This definition will
>   produce: **Test**.) On the other hand, the new commands
>   `\textbf{\textit{Test}}` will behave as expected producing:
>   ***Test***. Apart from that, with the former commands there is no
>   ‘italic correction’, cf. for instance halfhearted (`{\it
>   half}hearted`) to halfhearted (`\textit{half}hearted`).

Answer (score 6):

The `_` character is 'special', and is used for a subscript in math mode. Options for including it in text include

- Escape the `_` as `\_` (awkward if you have a lot),
- Load the `underscore` package, to allow `_` to be used in text,
- Using the `\detokenize` primitive, for verbatim-like text.