# Umlauts in label

Tags: cross-referencing, luatex, characters

I'm using LuaLaTeX and wonder why I cannot label theorems with words containing umlauts. For example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{luatextra}
\usepackage[utf8]{luainputenc}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}
\begin{document}
    \begin{thm} {\bf Exämple's_theorem}
             %\label{Exämple's theorem} % does not work
              \label{Exaemple's_theorem} % does work

        Lorem ipsum etc.
    \end{thm}
\end{document}
```

Has anyone a clue why this is and - maybe how to resolve this ?
I'm just curious for the underlying reason. Writing 'ae' instead of 'ä' is not a hard thing to do, so no solution is no problem.

Additionally `lacheck` says you shouldn't use spaces in labels, but there occurred no errors during compilation - another white spot in my knowing `latex`/`luatex` map.

Comment: With "normal" LaTeX umlauts are usually active characters, i.e. macros, which are fragile and can't be written without issues into auxiliary files. No idea, if LuaLaTeX is any better here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The package **luainputenc** can be useful to convert legacy documents to LuaLaTeX use and should not be used in new documents.

The following document works:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{fontspec} % don't forget it with lualatex
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}

\begin{document}
\begin{thm}[Exämple's theorem]\label{Exämple's theorem}
Lorem ipsum etc.
\end{thm}
\end{document}
```

Note that **amsthm** should be loaded before **fontspec** and `_` can't be used in normal text without protection. Also, theorem names or attributions should be given as optional argument to the environment.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but when i call lualatex test.tex - the compiler asks for XeTeX.

additionally thanks for noting the luainputenc - is not necessary

Comment: could it be an error due to the fact that i use `texlive-2009` (I'm on a debian machine)

Comment: i had a not so brief look on the `fontspec` documentation and found "fontspec needs an up to date texlive 2011 installation" so no fontspecfun for me (for now)

Comment: @epsilonhalbe There's fontspec also in TeX Live 2009, but I believe it doesn't work with LuaLaTeX. Actually it's not necessary; but the best is to upgrade to TeX Live 2011.

Comment: i tried to upgrade a few packages - but nothing is working the way i want - i'll upgrade as soon as i can afford some time for it. thanks anyway and good night ;-)

Answer (score 2):

You have some misstakes in your code:

- the command `\bf` is obsolete. For more details see [l2tabu](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/info/l2tabu)
- every theorem-environment has an optional argument with the title of the theorem
- the underscore needs special handling.
- don't use special characters like German umlaut in labels.

Some information are provided in my earlier answer: [Despite using backslash dollar sign, error persists](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29448/despite-using-backslash-dollar-sign-error-persists)

Comment: +1 for the l2tabu document - very insightful