# Unwanted double spacing

Tags: line-spacing

I have the following LaTeX code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}

\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,table]{xcolor}

\newcommand{\ADDRESS}{
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.40\textwidth}
\begin{flushright}
{\bf \textcolor{gray}{\tiny{My company}}}\\
\textcolor{gray}{\tiny{1 West 1st Avenue}}\\
\textcolor{gray}{\tiny{City Province}}\\
\textcolor{gray}{\tiny{Tel: 1-777-777-7777}}\\
\textcolor{blue}{\tiny{\href{mailto:customerservice@mycompany.com}{customerservice@mycompany.com}}}\\
\textcolor{blue}{\tiny{\href{http://www.mycompany.com/}{www.mycompany.com}}}\\
\end{flushright}
\end{minipage}
}

\begin{document}
\hfill \ADDRESS
\end{document}
```

However, when I compile this document I get some unwanted double spacing ... How can I get rid of the double spacing and why does the double spacing show up ?

Answer (score 5):

The spacing "problems" stem from a local font change. If you change the font globally, it would also affect the `\baselineskip`, which is the apparent "double spacing":

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{hyperref}% http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,table]{xcolor}% http://ctan.org/pkg/xcolor

\newcommand{\ADDRESS}{
  \begin{minipage}[t]{0.40\textwidth}
    \raggedleft\tiny%
    {\bfseries\textcolor{gray}{My company}}\\
    \textcolor{gray}{1 West 1st Avenue}\\
    \textcolor{gray}{City Province}\\
    \textcolor{gray}{Tel: 1-777-777-7777}\\
    \textcolor{blue}{\href{mailto:customerservice@mycompany.com}{customerservice@mycompany.com}}\\
    \textcolor{blue}{\href{http://www.mycompany.com/}{www.mycompany.com}}
  \end{minipage}
}

\begin{document}
\hfill \ADDRESS
\end{document}​
```

Note the use of switches `\bfseries` (for **bold font**) and `\tiny` (for font size), as well as `\raggedleft` to remove some vertical space added by the `flushright` environment. The use of `\bfseries` is local to the first item in your `\ADDRESS`.

Using Marco's suggestion, using `\color{gray}` and `\color{blue}` would also suffice in setting the colour within some scope `{...}`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{hyperref}% http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,table]{xcolor}% http://ctan.org/pkg/xcolor

\newcommand{\ADDRESS}{
  \begin{minipage}[t]{0.40\textwidth}
    \raggedleft\tiny%
    {\color{gray}{\bfseries My company} \\
    1 West 1st Avenue \\
    City Province \\
    Tel: 1-777-777-7777} \\
    {\color{blue} \href{mailto:customerservice@mycompany.com}{customerservice@mycompany.com} \\
    \href{http://www.mycompany.com/}{www.mycompany.com}}
  \end{minipage}
}

\begin{document}
\hfill \ADDRESS
\end{document}​
```

Also see [Will two-letter font style commands (`\bf`, `\it`,...) ever be resurrected in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/15361/5764)

Comment: @Werner: A simple `\color{gray}` and `\color{blue}` can simplify the code. You don't have any problems with unbalanced brackets. Whatever I also want to link to this answer: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29448/despite-using-backslash-dollar-sign-error-persists/29449#29449

Comment: @MarcoDaniel: Simple and effective suggestions. Thanks, added.