# Word not hyphenated when surrounded by $ signs, and causing errors without $ signs

Tags: errors, hyphenation, keywords

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Despite using backslash dollar sign, error persists](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29448/despite-using-backslash-dollar-sign-error-persists)

I don't know why, but the word `kAudioUnitSubType_RemoteIO` is causing problems for me when I type it. I tried surrounding it with dollar signs but because it is a long word and it's position is at the end of the current line latex is ignoring my margins and just continuing with that one word.

Any ideas how I can fix this?

*Edit: If I don't surround the word with dollar-signs I'm getting [these errors.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NMTuc.png) But when I do surround it with dollar-signs, it's not being hyphenated and it looks like this:*

[image]

Comment: If the only problem is, that the word is not automatically hyphenated, you should say so in the title. Otherwise a MWE and a screenshot would be very helpful.

Comment: I updated the post and added some screenshots.