# Remove math from command parameter to get only the letters

Tags: math-mode, macros, cross-referencing, indexing

I use a little command, which prints new defined terms in bold, adds a label and adds them to the index.

`\newcommand*{\defined}[1]{{\bf #1}\label{#1}\index{#1}}`

Now if I do `\defined{$G$-invariant}` the label isn't working and the index entry is ordered in the wrong place. I think that's got to do with the math dollar sign. Is there a way to strip this and get for label and index just the G?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436). Don't use commands like `\bf` It's obsolete: See: http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/info/l2tabu or this answer: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29448/despite-using-backslash-dollar-sign-error-persists/29449#29449

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Next comment: The issue with `\label` can't work. There is no reference point.

Comment: @MarcoDaniel Why? `\label` writes not only a number, but also the page number and it's common to use a `\label` for referring to the page with `\pageref`

Comment: @egreg: I would work with `\href`. If you use `nameref` it fails

Comment: It would be possible to strip the dollars; but what will you get with `\defined{$\Gamma$-function}`? I'd definitely go with the optional argument for sorting.

Answer (score 5):

Here's how I'd fix it: add a second, optional parameter as the sort key and label:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{xparse}
\NewDocumentCommand{\defined}{mg}{%
    {\bfseries #1}%
    \IfNoValueTF{#2}
        {\index{#1}\label{#1}}
        {\index{#2@#1}\label{#2}}
    }
\makeindex
\begin{document}
\defined{$G$-invariant}    % Probably does it wrong

\defined{$G$-invariant}{G-invariant}
\printindex
\end{document}
```

As an alternative, in accordance with @egreg's suggestion, using the 'Traditional' way of doing optional arguments:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{xparse}
\NewDocumentCommand{\defined}{om}{%
    {\bfseries #2}%
    \IfNoValueTF{#1}
        {\index{#2}\label{#2}}
        {\index{#1@#2}\label{#1@#2}}
    }
\makeindex
\begin{document}
\defined{$G$-invariant}

\defined[G-invariant]{$G$-invariant}
\printindex
\end{document}
```

Comment: Why the `g` argument instead of a more usual `om` syntax? A `mg` syntax is quite confusing, in my opinion. The `\label` has its use, for `\pageref`.

Comment: @egreg I sort of robbed it from [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/48361/344). I'm still only beginning to try out `\NewDocumentCommand`; and I *do* really like the idea of having the optional things last.

Comment: If it's optional, then use `m`, not `g`.

Comment: @egreg Oh, OK, I'll have to go back to the manual. Is my answer actually wrong? (That is, even worse than confusing?)

Comment: No, it's not wrong; but the vast majority of LaTeX commands have the optional argument first and in brackets `[...]`, so users generally expect this form rather than an optional argument in braces after the mandatory one. Having a consistent interface helps.

Comment: @egreg OK, thank you for good advice. Now, I've added a second answer (so it doesn't get too confusing). I hope that is appropriate.

Comment: Cool! This works as a charme, and yes, you're right, better wo work with an optional Parameter. Is there a way to have in the index not the pagenumber but the current ams-theorem number?

Comment: PS. Or to define a own theoremstyle which takes #3 as the term to be \defined and added to the index, but for the same reason allows an optional parameter for sorting?

Comment: @heinzlein I'm sorry, I'm not sure, but I think that might be a new question, if I understand the rules OK

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/98626/automatically-add-theorems-to-index-and-label-them

Answer (score 5):

I'd definitely go with Bianca Lobo's solution (the alternative one, really). But, just for fun, here's another way.

It's possible to strip `$` symbols, but this is not the only problem: if you strip `$` from `\defined{$\Gamma$-function}` you'll get into troubles. Moreover, simply stripping the `$` would leave incorrect entries in the index in any case.

However one can use the `@` feature of `\index`: with

```
\index{something@something else}
```

MakeIndex will use `something` for the sorting, while writing "something else" as the index entry.

Here's a complicated way to do what you want:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse,l3regex}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\makeindex

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\defined}{om}
 {
  \textbf{#2}
  \IfNoValueTF{#1}
   % No optional argument: do the complicated test
   { \heinz_index:n {#2} }
   % Optional argument: use the simplest way
   { \label{#1}\index{#1@#2} }
 }
\tl_new:N \l__heinz_index_tl
\cs_new_protected:Npn \heinz_index:n #1
 {
  % test if a $ is present in the argument
  \tl_if_in:nnTF { #1 } { $ }
   { \__heinz_strip:n { #1 } } % a $ is scanned
   { \index{#1} }              % no $, simple case
 }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \__heinz_strip:n #1
 {
  % stringify the argument
  \tl_set:Nx \l__heinz_index_tl { \tl_to_str:n { #1 } }
  % remove $, backslash, spaces
  \regex_replace_all:nnN { ( \$ | \\ | \s ) } { } \l__heinz_index_tl
  % produce the \index command and the label
  \__heinz_do_double_index:nV { #1 } \l__heinz_index_tl
 }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__heinz_do_double_index:nn #1 #2
 {
  \exp_args:NV \label \l__heinz_index_tl
  \index{#2@#1}
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \__heinz_do_double_index:nn { nV }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\defined{face}

\defined{$G$-invariant}

\defined{group}

\defined{$\Gamma$-function}

\defined[C-transform]{$\mathcal{C}$-transform}

\pageref{G-invariant}

\clearpage

\printindex

\end{document}
```

However, in some cases you'll have to express it in the form

```
\defined[<sorting key>]{<argument>}
```

as the stripping performed in the case of `$\mathcal{C}$-transform` will do no good. One might add to the list of tokens to be stripped off, but this is error prone and it doesn't seem really a sensible thing to do.

Note also that you have to use the "stripped" version in `\pageref`, so do `\pageref{G-invariant}` and not `\pageref{$G$-invariant}`. In any case a label such as `$\Gamma$-function` would be illegal.

Answer (score 2):

Using the etex `\scantokens` you can locally set `$` to be ignored. This removes it from the label key and also from the sort key used by makeindex. The original math string is used after the `@` field so it is typeset in the index.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{makeidx}


\newcommand*{\defined}[1]{%
{\catcode`\$=9
\scantokens{\gdef\tmp{#1}}}%
\textbf{#1}\label{\tmp}\index{\tmp@#1}}

\makeindex
\begin{document}


\defined{$G$-invariant}

\defined{foo-invariant}


\printindex
\end{document}
```